# How can I check if file exists, and if not kill the build?

Tags: ant

How can I stop a build, and notify the user if a file does not exist?  I know I can use the available task to set a property if a file exists, but I'm not sure how I would stop a build and echo something.

I would like to stick with core tasks if possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [fail task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) for all your failing needs.  The last example on that page is actually pretty much what you need

```
<fail message="Files are missing.">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <resourcecount count="2">
                <fileset id="fs" dir="." includes="one.txt,two.txt"/>
            </resourcecount>
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: Amazing how there is always another task that I have never heard about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

A little simpler (I wish it could be made simpler)

```
<fail message="file ${myfile} not set or missing">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <available file="${myfile}" />
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: Very clean and easy to understand

Answer (score 6):

Set your property and use the [Fail](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) task with the if attribute.

Comment: The `if` attribute checks for the *existence* of a property, not its value.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done more compactly (as indicated by Jason Punyon). Specifically, assuming the file you want is in the property `file`, do:

```
<available file="${file}" property="file.exists" />
<fail message="File missing: ${file}" unless="file.exists" />
```

Comment: I think that the unless condition on the fail attribute is much more readable and long term maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of checks are common, so it might pay off to use a macro.
Here is a macro based on the solution by leonbloy:

```
<macrodef name="require">
    <attribute name="file"/>
    <attribute name="message" default="file @{file} not set or missing"/>
    <sequential>
        <fail message="@{message}">
            <condition>
            <not>
                <available file="@{file}" />
            </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Use like this:

```
<require file="${myfile}" />
```

or

```
<require file="${myfile}" message="my custom message" />
```